# Password protect a page, and send notification email when logged in

Tags: html, forms, passwords

Is there a way to password protect a page with an array of passwords (which in this case is email addresses), and then once someone successfully logs in a notification is sent to a specified email address letting us know that someone has logged in with the given password (email address).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you'll need to use PHP, and your question unfortunately isn't something that can be answered in a couple of lines.

Below won't fully give you your answers, but it may lead you in the right direction to achieving them:

For a tutorial on user login using PHP $_POST , you could try [here](http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/simple-registration-system-php-mysql). Instead of reading the username and passwords from a mysql database, it would be simple enough to read in from an array defined in your PHP file.

For mail, below is a php function to email users their password once it's been reset. You should be able to get the idea of how the mail() function works from it and what variables to populate so you can change it for your own needs. You would call the email function once you've determined that a user has logged in succesfully.

```
public static function  EmailPassword($user_email, $user, $password)
 {

    $mailfrom = "user@website.com.au";


    $eol = "\n";
    $content = $eol;
    $content .= "Password for " . $user . " is " . $password . $eol; 


    $subject = "Pasword reset for " . $user . " at website.com.au";

    $boundary = md5(uniqid(time()));

    $header  = 'From: '.$mailfrom.$eol;
    $header .= 'Reply-To: '.$mailfrom.$eol;
    $header .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.$eol;
    $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="'.$boundary.'"'.$eol;
    $header .= 'X-Mailer: PHP v'.phpversion().$eol;

    $body  = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.'.$eol.$eol;
    $body .= '--'.$boundary.$eol;
    $body .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1'.$eol;
    $body .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'.$eol;
    $body .= $eol.stripslashes($content).$eol;       



    //send the email
    mail($user_email, $subject, $body, $header);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this with a server-side language like PHP. You can't do this with pure HTML and Javascript, unless you plan to store the usernames and passwords in a plaintext array in your Javascript (Don't do this, it is madness!).

If you use PHP, you can send the username and password data via POST, and have the user accounts stored in a MySQL Database. You can then lookup the username and password and see if they match, and if they do, then you could use something like PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function to email the user.